# SQL SELECT query for two values within same field

Tags: php, sql

I am fairly new to SQL queries and I am having trouble performing a query on an already running database.

I need to run two queries, first to check who has signed up 3 days ago and has not made any orders and has not receieved an email giving them an offer. This works great.

The next query is to check that a customer has signed up 7 days ago, not made any orders and has receieved the 3 day email. I can get it to do that but I also need to check that they have not already receieved the second email and this is the part that is confusing me. Even when the customer has been sent the 2 email when I run the query again they still appear.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT c.customerID, c.email, c.forename, c.date 
      FROM customers c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_headers o ON o.customerID=c.customerID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN no_order_mail_sent m ON m.customerID=c.customerID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN automated_email_discount e ON e.customerID=c.customerID 
     WHERE m.customerID IS NULL
       AND o.customerID IS NULL
       AND e.customerID IS NOT NULL 
       AND e.discount_code_id='1'
       AND e.discount_code_id!='2' 
       AND STR_TO_DATE(c.date, '%Y%m%d') ='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$days.'days'))."'
";
```

The two discount codes are 1 for first email (5% discount) and 2 for the second email (10% discount) which is the value I am trying to check for that is within the database.

I am running the query in PHP. Any help would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: '1' <> '2' for all values of '1'.

Comment: @wildplasser What do you mean by '1' <> '2' for all values of '1'? Sorry new to this.

Comment: @MattGibson sample data for all tables stated?

Comment: `AND e.discount_code_id = '1'
       AND e.discount_code_id != '2'` . The second condition is redundant.

Comment: @wildplasser I get what you mean, any ideas on what I need to do to get what I need?

Comment: The left JOIN e `ON e.customerID=c.customerID ... AND e.customerID IS NOT NULL` Makes no sense to me. IMHO It could be replaced by a plain JOIN. BTW: Is this generated code?

Comment: @wildplasser Yeah I see your point after reading it up. Nope, typed it myself. Now just need to get the ones who have not received the second email so code 2. Any ideas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd rename the date column (date is a reserved word), and I'd replace the two "left join where id IS NULL" by NOT EXISTS() constructs. I don't know why you perform the date-arithmetic on strings, but that could be a mysql-thing (mysql does not have operators on date+intervals?) There is also a corner case when the date field IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude "LEFT OUTER JOIN automated_email_discount" and conditions for this table from query and add following condition:

```
And c.customerID not in (select customerID from automated_email_discount where discount_code_id='2')
```

Here is the final statement:

```
SELECT c.customerID, c.email, c.forename, c.date 
      FROM customers c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_headers o ON o.customerID=c.customerID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN no_order_mail_sent m ON m.customerID=c.customerID 
     WHERE m.customerID IS NULL
       AND o.customerID IS NULL
       And c.customerID not in (select customerID from automated_email_discount where discount_code_id='2')
       AND STR_TO_DATE(c.date, '%Y%m%d') ='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$days.'days'))."'
";
```